# Поиск подстрок одного столбца в строках другого столбца Excel c помощью Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Здраствуйте! Нужно проверить вхождение подстрок из одного столбца во все строки из другого столбца файла Excel, и в столбце "Result" получить True/False. Пробовал реализовать вот так:

```
def check_df(df2):
    return  str(df2['1']) in str(df_comp1['2'])
df_func['Result'] = df_func.apply(check_df, axis=1)
```

Но не получил результат который надо. Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

```
dataframe = {
'1': ['ELEC', 'CARGO','poiu','ffpo','tytok','basd'], 
'2': ['ec','po','ba','','','']
}
```

Желаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaxU, пример данных добавил, так же скрин желаемого результату, нужно найти вхождение подстрок столбца "2" в строках столбца "1", количество записей может отличаться

Comment: но каким образом у вас TRUE для 4й и 7й строк??

Comment: "basd" имеет в себе подстроку "ba" со столбца "2", так же подстроки могут относиться к нескольким значениям в столбце "1", никак не получалось реализовать самому

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
pat = "(?:{})".format(df["2"].replace("", np.nan).dropna().str.lower().str.cat(sep="|"))

df["Result"] = df["1"].str.lower().str.contains(pat)
```

результат:

```
In [379]: df
Out[379]:
       1   2  Result
0   ELEC  ec    True
1  CARGO  po   False
2   poiu  ba    True
3   ffpo        True
4  tytok       False
5   basd        True
```

---

Можно воспользоваться параметром `case=False` как в ответе @SergFSM:

```
pat = "(?:{})".format(df["2"].replace("", np.nan).dropna().str.cat(sep="|"))

df["Result"] = df["1"].str.contains(pat, case=False)
```

результат:

```
In [385]: df
Out[385]:
       1   2  Result
0   ELEC  ec    True
1  CARGO  po   False
2   poiu  ba    True
3   ffpo        True
4  tytok       False
5   basd        True
```

Answer (score 2):

решение похоже на [уже предложенное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1370957/457260):

```
df['Result'] = df['1'].str.contains('|'.join(i for i in df['2'].to_list() if i),
                                    case=False, regex=True)
df
'''
       1   2  Result
0   ELEC  ec    True
1  CARGO  po   False
2   poiu  ba    True
3   ffpo        True
4  tytok       False
5   basd        True
```

Comment: да, я совсем забыл о ключе `case=False` - благодаря ему можно сократить код )

Comment: @MaxU, после изменения возникла такая ошибка: TypeError: sequence item 10615: expected str instance, float found. Как можно исправить?

Comment: @pion, `"после изменения ..."` - после какого изменения?

Comment: @MaxU, после сокращения кода, возникла така ошибка

Comment: @pion, дополнил свой ответ...

Comment: @MaxU, здраствуйте, возможно можно переделать ваш ответ, что бы подстроку искало так же в  середине и в конце строки? а не только совпадение с начала строки. Пробовал переделать, пока что не получилось.

Comment: @pion, а сейчас как ищет?? В первой строке `ELEC` - находит `ec` в __конце__ строки

Comment: @MaxU понимаю, что немного позно, но как доделать,что би виводило значение столбца df['2'] вместо true i false?